# How can I run a batch file on startup in Windows 10 using the cmder console emulator?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmder

I use a batch file to connect to proxy servers, which I have set to run on startup in Windows 10.

The batch file that runs on startup triggers three further batch files (in order to run three separate proxies simultaneously) and this results in three instances of the default Windows 10 command prompt running.

My preferred command prompt is [cmder](http://cmder.net/), specifically for the reason that it allows tabbed windows (it self-contains numerous instances).

For example, I have three command prompts running as three separate tabs/instances within a single interface.

Is it possible to make the batch file that runs on startup run in cmder so that I only have one window instead of three?

Comment: Work through [this link](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/457)

Comment: cmder is a repack. In ConEmu you may use [Default Terminal](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html) feature and [-new_console](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) switch to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be possible to change your script extensions to e.g. .cmdr and then associate to cmder. Then just add your script.cmdr to the Startup group.

Answer (score 0):

You create the batch file, and then put it in the start-up file.  This has been the way of the world since windows 3.1 days.

If the program allows you to open new tabs and talk to them, then that's all that is really needed.   Usually, look for specific commands in the cmder shell.  Take Command does this.

Since the thing is using conemu, i imagine you would look into that program's options about opening a new tab in a batch file.

If you don't need to see the instance of cmder, you can minimise it.

It is possible to even launch gui programs.